# strpos and substr on String

Tags: php, substr, strpos

I have an HTML file which contains nothing but text. There are no styles or anything.

The text looks like:

```
ID     NAME     ANOTHER-ID-11-LETTERS      MAJOR
```

Example:

```
20 Paul Mark Zedd 10203040506 Software Engineering
```

`ID` and `ANOTHER-ID-11-LETTER` are numbers..
`NAME` And `MAJOR` are normal text and also contain spaces.

How can I strip them and make each word or each content in new-line using PHP?

Expected result:

```
20
Paul Mark Zedd
10203040506
Software Engineering
```

Comment: did you check if they are separated by tabs instead of just spaces?

Comment: or are they perhaps fixed-width?

Comment: if the ID and 'another-id' are always digits, then use a `split()` on the digits.

Comment: they separated by spaces only
and the texts are not in english actually it's in arabic

Comment: @MarcB if u will use split till where? 'speace'?
what's about the other-text it will also contain spaces' ?

Comment: `$data = preg_split('your string', '/(\d+)/', -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE)`. Relevant docs: http://php.net/preg_split

Comment: looks like id and another id are always numbers, you could us regex to get the 2 IDs and split using the numbers since there is only one field to the right, and one field in between? After you edit the first space is always after the first id, so get that and trim it odd, then split the rest by the long number using regex

Comment: That works as long as there are no numbers in `NAME` or `MAJOR`.

Comment: I thought about to use this way,
First getline
find the last number before find first text then make <br/> after it
then the same find the last letter before find first number <br/>
repeating it again

Comment: looks like the long id is probably sufficiently long to be unlikly to be in NAME if it is always 11 digits, and the first number can be found as first "thing" upto the space?

Comment: would something like this as a rexex with 4 matching groups work? `([0-9]*?)\s(.*?)([0-9]{11})\s(.*)`

`$test  = preg_match("/([0-9]*?)\s(.*?)([0-9]{11})\s(.*)/is", "20 Paul Mark Zedd 10203040506 Software Engineering",$matchs);
print_r($matchs)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the first item is always a number, followed by a space, followed by a name which can be anything, followed by a number which is 11 digits folowed by some more text.

You can use regex and the above details to split the string

```
$test  = preg_match("/([0-9]*?)\s(.*?)([0-9]{11})\s(.*)/is", "20 Paul Mark Zedd 10203040506 Software Engineering",$matchs);
print_r($matchs)
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 20 Paul Mark Zedd 10203040506 Software Engineering
    [1] => 20
    [2] => Paul Mark Zedd 
    [3] => 10203040506
    [4] => Software Engineering
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a

> preg_match:

```
#([\d]*)\s([a-zA-Z\s]*)\s([\d]*)\s([a-zA-Z\s]*)#
```

Example output:

```
array (
  0 => '20 Paul Mark Zedd 10203040506 SoftwareEngineering',
  1 => '20',
  2 => 'Paul Mark Zedd',
  3 => '10203040506',
  4 => 'SoftwareEngineering',
)
```